# How do i parse this string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

this url

```
"?route=system/template/update&template_id=22&token=200bfaa1f5d6cda4c782f98b15f32e7f"
```

and i just need the token out of it

```
 200bfaa1f5d6cda4c782f98b15f32e7f
```

how is the best way to parse that out...it seems to always be last

Comment: As you can see many of the answers vary their approach and some may not fit if the URL is even slightly different, this is mainly because the answers are referring to this specific case and no other variants since they don't know about them, if this is the only possible "form" you could encounter the URL, this is fine, but if you may have `&otherthing=123` at the end, some may not work, maybe a clarification would help.

Comment: your right i noticed that there maybe another get var at the end...so i went with this input.match(/token=(\w+)/)[1]

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
var
  input = "?route=system/template/update&template_id=22&token=200bfaa1f5d6cda4c782f98b15f32e7f",
  output = input.split("=").splice(-1)[0]; // output === "200bfaa1f5d6cda4c782f98b15f32e7f"
```

Or, if you're not sure that the token is always the last value:

```
var 
  input = "?route=system/template/update&template_id=22&token=200bfaa1f5d6cda4c782f98b15f32e7f&foo=bar&baz=spam",
  output = input.substring(input.indexOf('token=')).split(/[=&]/)[1]; // output === "200bfaa1f5d6cda4c782f98b15f32e7f"
```

Comment: works great esp since the token is always last. Other wise this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Or use regular expression. In this case it will be like

Format

```
var re = /token\=(\S+)/i;
alert(url.match(re)[1]);
```

Comment: or... alert(input.match(/token=(\w+)/)[1])

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the other part:

```
s = "?route=system/template/update&template_id=22&token=200bfaa1f5d6cda4c782f98b15f32e7f"

s.replace(/.*token=/, '')

#=> "200bfaa1f5d6cda4c782f98b15f32e7f"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "?route=system/template/update&template_id=22&token=200bfaa1f5d6cda4c782f98b15f32e7f";
s.match("[0-9a-z]*$");
```

Displays `"200bfaa1f5d6cda4c782f98b15f32e7f"`